# Adjust height of title in shinydashboard header with logo

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have this code for making my dashboard:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(fresh)
mytheme <- create_theme(
  adminlte_color(
    light_blue = "#004e70"
  ),
  adminlte_sidebar(
    width = "400px",
    dark_bg = "#3c3b3b",
    dark_hover_bg = "#004e70",
    dark_color = "white"
  )
)

Header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Labor Market Discrimination in Ecuador",
  titleWidth = 450,
  tags$li(a(img(src = "BID_Blanco.png",
                title = "IDB Logo", height = "60px"),
            tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 70px; padding-top:10px; padding-botton:10px;")),
          class = "dropdown")
)

Tabs <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 70px}"),
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("General", tabName = "general"),
    menuItem("Trial", tabName = "by_trial"),
    menuItem("Sex", tabName = "by_ss")
  )
)

Body <- dashboardBody(
  use_theme(mytheme),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "general"),
    tabItem(tabName = "by_trial"),
    tabItem(tabName = "by_ss")
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  Header, 
  Tabs,
  Body
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This produces this:

[image]

What can I do to make the title taller (where does it say "Labor Market Discrimination in Ecuador")? like the same height as the blue bar where the logo is

and to get rid of the black space where my tabs start? (just above "general") This is one of my very first shinydashboards, so I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `height` to the `.logo` span (make sure to address the `<span>` with enough specificity to make sure your rule eventually applies):

```r
Body <- dashboardBody(
  use_theme(mytheme),
  tags$head(
    tags$style("
       .left-side, .main-sidebar {
          padding-top: 70px;
       }
       .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
          height: 70px; 
          display: inline-flex;
          align-items: center;
       }")
     ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "general"),
    tabItem(tabName = "by_trial"),
    tabItem(tabName = "by_ss")
  )
)
```

[image: Header of a Shinydashboard Page wiht the logo span spanning the whole area of the surrounding header tag]

Comment: This worked nicely! Thank you only thing i'd add is to change this one `tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 70px}")` until it fits